# How to add months in given date in progress openedge

Tags: openedge

How to Perform Arithmetic Operations with Dates and Times in progress openedge.

eg: Add day,month,year in given date.

Comment: This is a very broad question, and you show no effort of your own. Did you try a tutorial, and if so just where did you get stuck?

Comment: Thanks Rory ,

First i tried to my self but i did not found exact solution . can you share some notes on openedge for learning purpose . Actually i am totally beginner and i have only one resource i.e you guys . so please help me to learn openedge. 
Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

`ADD-INTERVAL` is your friend. For simple dates and days you can also work with + and -.

> ADD-INTERVAL(datetime, interval-amount, interval-unit)
>
> Adds a time interval to, or subtracts a time interval from, a DATE, DATETIME, or DATETIME-TZ value, and returns the new value.
>
> **datetime**
>
> An expression whose value is a DATE, DATETIME, or DATETIME-TZ.
>
> **interval-amount**
>
> A signed integer (positive or negative) indicating the amount of time you want > to add to or subtract from datetime value.
>
> **interval-unit**
>
> A character constant, or a character expression that evaluates to one of the  > following time units: ‘years', ‘months', ‘weeks', ‘days', 'hours', ‘minutes', > ‘seconds' or ‘milliseconds'. These values are case insensitive and may be 
>   singular.

**Example:**

```
DEFINE VARIABLE dToday AS DATE        NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE dNow   AS DATETIME    NO-UNDO.

dToday = TODAY.

DISPLAY dToday                             LABEL "Today"       WITH FRAME frDate SIDE-LABELS 1 COLUMN.
DISPLAY dToday + 1                         LABEL "Tomorrow 1"  WITH FRAME frDate.
DISPLAY ADD-INTERVAL(dToday,  1, "day")    LABEL "Tomorrow 2"  WITH FRAME frDate.
DISPLAY ADD-INTERVAL(dToday,  1, "week")   LABEL "Next week"   WITH FRAME frDate.
DISPLAY ADD-INTERVAL(dToday, -1, "week")   LABEL "Last week"   WITH FRAME frDate.
DISPLAY ADD-INTERVAL(dToday,  1, "month")  LABEL "Next month"  WITH FRAME frDate.
DISPLAY ADD-INTERVAL(dToday,  1, "year")   LABEL "Next year"   WITH FRAME frDate.

dNow = NOW.

DISPLAY dNOW                              LABEL "Now"           WITH FRAME frDateTime SIDE-LABELS 1 COLUMN.
DISPLAY ADD-INTERVAL(dNow,  1, "hour")    LABEL "Next hour"     WITH FRAME frDateTime.
DISPLAY ADD-INTERVAL(dNow, 30, "minute")  LABEL "In 30 minutes" WITH FRAME frDateTime.

DISPLAY INTERVAL( dToday + RANDOM(1,30), dToday, "minutes") LABEL "Difference in minutes".
```

You can also use `INTERVAL` to get the difference between two dates or datetimes.

> INTERVAL ( datetime1 , datetime2 , interval-unit )
>
> Returns the time interval between two DATE, DATETIME, or DATETIME-TZ values as an INT64 value.
>
> **datetime1**
>
> An expression whose value is a DATE, DATETIME, or DATETIME-TZ.
>
> **datetime2**
>
> An expression whose value is a DATE, DATETIME, or DATETIME-TZ.
>
> **interval-unit**
>
> A character constant, or a character expression that evaluates to one of the 
>   following time units: ‘years', ‘months', ‘weeks', ‘days', 'hours', ‘minutes', > ‘seconds' or ‘milliseconds'. These values are case insensitive and might be 
>   singular.